# repeat each item in a list n times, x times into rows ; in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

So let's say I have the list

```
item1
item2
item3
```

I need a formula to make it look like this -

where each item in the list is repeated X times , Y times. So in this case each item is repeated 3 times 4 times - for a total of (3 * 3 * 4) rows

```
item1
item1
item1
item2
item2
item2
item3
item3
item3
item1
item1
item1
item2
item2
item2
item3
item3
item3
item1
item1
item1
item2
item2
item2
item3
item3
item3
item1
item1
item1
item2
item2
item2
item3
item3
item3
```

so far I have this

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(REPT(A1:A3&";", 3), ,999^99), ";")))
```

which repeats each item 5 times, once like

```
item1
item1
item1
item2
item2
item2
item3
item3
item3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=ArrayFormula(FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REPT(A1:A3 & ",",D2),",")) & ";",E2),";"))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(TRIM(SPLIT(REPT(QUERY(
 FLATTEN(SPLIT(REPT(A1:A3&"♦♥", D1), "♥")),,9^9), D2), "♦"))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Along similar lines to the other answers so far:

```
=INDEX(SORT(SPLIT(FLATTEN(INT(SEQUENCE(1,D1*D2,0)/D1)*COUNTA(A1:A5)+SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A1:A5))&"|"&A1:A5),"|")),,2)
```

[image]